# Output of patch

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, diff, patch

File1:

```
1;1
2;2
3;3
```

File2

```
2;3
3;3
4;4
```

"Diff" will produce:

```
1,2c1
< 1;1
< 2;2
---
> 2;3
3a3
> 4;4
```

and the usage of "patch" would lead to

```
2;3
3;3
4;4
```

Is there any possibility to display the deleted lines (1;1) too? Is it possible to add a prefix to any line appearing in the patch file as

```
(DEL-1;1)
UPD-2;3
UNC-3;3
INS-4;4
```

and the usage of standard tools?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `diff -u` output may be more to your liking, although an edit will still show as a deletion and an addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think unified diff format `diff -u`, will give you the information you want.

```
--- file1   2012-02-22 14:29:43.523242147 -0700
+++ file2   2012-02-22 14:29:51.053115158 -0700
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-1;1
-2;2
+2;3
 3;3
+4;4
```

Comment: Or a context diff: `diff -c`.  But unified diff output is more compact than context diff, so `diff -u` is the better choice.

Comment: @Toru you're welcome. The create of Python created a description of the output format (for reference): http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=164293